# Populate UITableView only after the data source is not empty

Tags: objective-c, uitableview

I have this simple implementation, that prepares an array what I need to use as a data source of a `UITableView`. The problem is, when I run the code it crashes because the `requestWithCompletionHandler` block obtains it's value after the setup of the table view. So there is no index value for the cell.

My question is, that how could I "activate" the table view only when the `self.json` array has it's value? Or what would be the proper workaround to avoid crashing because the empty array?

> error message:
>
> ```
> Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '*** -[__NSArrayM objectAtIndexedSubscript:]: index 0 beyond bounds for empty array'
> ```

```
   @property (strong, nonatomic) NSMutableArray *json;


- (void)viewDidLoad {

 [super viewDidLoad];  
  self.json =[[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

 [self.api requestWithCompletionHandler:^(NSArray<NSDictionary *> * result, NSError * error) {

     for (NSDictionary* x in result) {
            NSLog(@"object: %@", [x objectForKey:@"postDate"]);

            [self.json addObject:x];

        }

    }];

}   

 - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"cellF";
    ArticleFeedCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    NSDictionary *diction = self.json[indexPath.row];

    cell.articleWebsiteLabel.text = diction[@"website"];

    return cell;
}
```

Comment: show code of method `numberOfRowsInSection`

Comment: if self.json.count > 0 {
return self.json.count;
} else {
return 0;
}

Comment: ArticleFeedCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

The above should be this
ArticleFeedCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

Apart from this your code looks fine. Can you send me your code I can fix it.

Comment: The `count` check in `numberOfRowsInSection` is redundant. Just `return self.json.count`. If it's `0` it **does** return `0`. And you need to reload the table view (on the main thread) after receiving the data. And why do you use a loop in the completion block? Just write `self.json = result.mutableCopy()`.