# Reloading UITableView after method finished in background thread

Tags: objective-c

I have a JSON parser that is responsible for getting the data that I would like to display in a `UITableView`. Everything seems to be correct, except, that I can't reload the table view when the block in the background obtained the data.

This is how I do it now:

```
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {


    self.arr =[[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    self.api = [API new];
    [self.api requestWithCompletionHandler:^(NSArray<NSDictionary *> * result, NSError * error) {

        for (NSDictionary* x in result) {
            NSLog(@"The whole dict object: %@", [x objectForKey:@"datum"]);
            //NSString *grr = [NSString stringWithString:[x objectForKey:@"datum"]];
            [self.arr addObject:x];
        }

        [self reloadTable];

    }];

//    if (self.arr.count > 1) {
//        [self reloadTable];
//    }
//


}

- (void) reloadTable {

      [self.tableView reloadData];

}
```

I tried to call a function when the task is ready, and also tried to reload the table when the array has content, but unfortunately there is a delay, and I can't do a UI task from the background.

My question is, that what would be the best solution to fix this? Is is possible to notify the reloadTable method somehow outside from the bg thread?

Comment: The answer was already in my comment to your [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54545335/populate-uitableview-only-after-the-data-source-is-not-empty). And why do you still use the uneccessary loop in the completion block?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried to call it on the main thread?

```
- (void) reloadTable {
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        [self.tableView reloadData];
    });
}
```

Comment: No. However, it seems totally fine and works perfectly. Sorry for the dumb question, but is this a standard/common solution to handle situations like this?

Comment: Yes whenever you want to access UI you must do it on the main thread, so when a background thread finishes its work you call an update method on the main thread. You can also use the notification center, but for this kind of task, `dispatch_async` is your man! (If it works for you, don't hesitate to accept the answer)

Answer (score 1):

multi-threaded controllers can get complicated. Here is some advice to help you out.

```
self.api = [API new]; // 1a: Created in the main thread.
[self.api requestWithCompletionHandler:^(NSArray<NSDictionary *> *result, NSError *error) {
    for (NSDictionary* x in result) {
        NSLog(@"The whole dict object: %@", [x objectForKey:@"datum"]);
        [self.arr addObject:x]; // 1b: Updated in the background.
    }

    [self reloadTable]; // 2: Calling a view controller method in the background.
}];
```

I see two warning flags here.

1. Objects created on the main thread should not be updated in the background.
2. Don't call view controller methods in the background.

The easy way out is to dispatch to the main thread right away.

```
self.api = [API new];
[self.api requestWithCompletionHandler:^(NSArray<NSDictionary *> *result, NSError *error) {
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        for (NSDictionary* x in result) {
            NSLog(@"The whole dict object: %@", [x objectForKey:@"datum"]);
            [self.arr addObject:x];
        }

        [self reloadTable];
    });
}];
```

There are many other ways of handling main thread/background thread interactions, but I would start with this.